# C++ Templates: dealing with long class names

Tags: c++, c++11

If using statements are barred from headers in CPP projects according to nearly everyone, and templates must be declared in the headers unless specific steps are taken to specifically list out the classes that will be accepted in the cpp file,

What is the manner in which the following header template declaration should be rendered readable:

```
template<class A>
SomeLibrary::LongNameClass<SomeLibrary::LongNameClass2,SomeLibrary::LongNameClass3>
unreadable_function(SomeLibrary::LongNameClass<SomeLibrary::...> input1, ... input2, ... omg){
        SomeLibrary::SomeFunction<SomeLibrary::LongNameClass<SomeLibrary::...
        etc.
}
```

Comment: Using an actual documentation for your function? You can split template / function parameters on multiple lines. If you have too much imbrication / arguments, maybe it's a design issue... And nothing prevent you from using `using` inside the function - Using outside would bring your `using` declaration in every file that includes your header, which you do not want.

Comment: Just don't try to squeeze everything into a single line.

Comment: @VTT not just visually unreadable.  Also: fingertips dying

Comment: Readable C++? Sounds blasphemous

Comment: If by "fingertips dying" you mean that typing that stuff takes much time then it could be a complaint opposite to *"improving readability"*. Note that code is read more often then written so spending more time properly formatting code (and adding comments) is never a bad idea.

Comment: @VTT well, it goes both ways: I need to write faster, read what I write, and not have to waste mental energy and development time transcribing long winded class names, during development--we (people who prefer typed, multiparadigm programming languages for bigger projects) are competing with python now, and I am more than proficient with python, so I have to qualify the time I spend in C++ with output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont be mistaken, the only banned statement is `using namespace <...>`.

The statement `using <alias> = <type>` as well as `typedef <type> <alias>` are still valid and widely used.

Comment: `using <...>` is also sub-par. But using some local alias is ok, I guess, provided you can make it super-unique. Actually, shove it in a `detail` namespace and refer to it there, yay (although be careful because the more you do this the more you're back to square one )

Comment: and--just to be clear--I am free to use usings in cpp files?  ALSO, if I create a namespace, I can use usings differently?

Comment: Aliases are fine, however the tricky part would be not to end up with names like `LongNameClassFromSomeLibrary`.

Comment: @bordeo With `using` is cpp-file there is still naming collision probability, but it will be only in this cpp-file, not entire project. 
About scope of `using` inside namespaces I'm not sure. Never have tried this

Comment: @SemyonBurov awesome, I will try that, and comment

Answer (score 0):

> What is the manner in which the following header template declaration
>   should be rendered readable:

- Use white-space to format your code for readability.
- Use trailing return types to make function names stand out.
- Use concise, meaningful identifiers.
- Provide high-level abstractions (sometimes just a typedef).

See [Kevlin Henney's talk](https://youtu.be/ZsHMHukIlJY) for more explanation.

```
namespace Some {

template<class A>
auto unreadable(LongName<...> input1,
                ... input2,
                ... omg)
 -> LongName<LongName2, LongName3>
{
    Some<LongName<...>>();
    etc.
}

} // namespace Some
```

Comment: what about typedefs within the namespace? Will these cause collisions when imported? I mean, if it is **in** the namespace, I would imagine I would always pick the same or similar alias names...

Comment: A typedef may be used to provide a meaningful abstraction, while at the same time shorten code. E.g. `typedef std::map <std::string, int, CaseInsensitiveLess> NameCount;`